# Two-way encryption with comparable result

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I encrypt a text using Laravel `Crypt::encrypt("text")` but everytime I get different results. I want the encrypted result to be compared in database.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE `encrypted_field` = "'.Crypt::encrypt('text').'"';
```

But because `Crypt::encrypt('text')` return different result every time, the query returns nothing.

How to deal with this problem?

Comment: That's a security property of semantic security. The question is *why* do you want to reduce security?

Comment: Read the post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881849/laravel-crypt-comparing-values

Comment: @ArtjomB. Wasn't that clear? because I want to compare two encrypted texts.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the `encrypt` method,that's the whole point of encryption and the `mcrypt` php's extension, to provide a mathematical way to secure your data, and because it's a mathematical process you will never get the same the result.You can `sha1` to encrypt your strings as it always return the same result for the same string.But I don't recommend it because it's not a secure method to encrypt data

Comment: @Harry SHA1 is in no way ***encryption*** at all. It's a hash, which is something completely different.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said I don't recommend this method, it's just an obfuscation. Just a way to make your data non-human readable.

Comment: @HarryGeo Nope, still wrong. What you're thinking about is probably an ***encoding*** like base 64. That's still not a hash. A good hash is in fact extremely secure for certain purposes like password storage. But it's still not encryption.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you want to do:

If you want to decrypt something in the future you can use

```
$encrypted = Crypt::encrypt('foobar');
$decrypted = Crypt::decrypt($encrypted); //returns foobar
```

In this case the encrypt value changes every time. But remember: if you change your app key you can't decrypt old strings with it.

But if you need just a Hash, e.g. for passwords being the same all the time, then you can use

```
$password = Hash::make('secret');
$password = bcrypt('secret'); // same as Hash::make
```

To compare the hash with a non hashed word you can use

```
if (Hash::check('secret', $hashedPassword))
{
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The direct and immediate answer is, you can't. Don't try, you'll just degrade your own security.

However, you can index encrypted information safely, through a process I call [blind indexing](https://paragonie.com/white-paper/2015-secure-php-data-encryption#index-encrypted-information).

1. Store the encrypted data, verbatim, and don't do anything to degrade the security of your encryption. **SERIOUSLY.**
2. In your PHP code, calculate `hash_hmac('sha256', $unencryptedData, $someVeryUnguessableKey)`.
3. Use this HMAC for indexing and comparison.

This allows you to perform lookups, in a blind manner, without having to weaken your encryption. However, be warned that the design as stated is not impervious to timing attacks, and be sure to log and rate-limit every attempt to access data (whether successful or not).